# How do I know what I should change in my DCGAN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am very new to the world of GANs, and I am well aware of how challenging they are to train. The problem is, I'm having a difficult time finding resources for my specific problems, so I thought I would just make a post here.

I am training a DCGAN using images from the *landscape* section of [this](https://www.kaggle.com/ipythonx/wikiart-gangogh-creating-art-gan) art dataset. I have a model built, but it doesn't work very well... at all. And I've spent many hours trying to tweak the architecture and different hyperparameters to fix it, but no significant progress has been made.

I've also noticed that it likes "picking a color palette" and generating very similar images in each epoch, which doesn't seem like correct behavior. This is an issue that has persisted throughout every update to the model I have made.

Here are some things that I have tried so far (this is my first StackOverflow post, so sorry if I don't give enough information):

1. Removed Dense layer in Generator, lowered batch size from 32 to 16
2. Brought batch size back up to 32, removed all dropout from Generator
3. Put Dropout back in G, lowered D learning rate to .001
4. Removed half of D Dropout, raised G learning rate .003
5. Changed D optimizer from Adam to SGD, lowered G learning rate to .002 raised D learning rate to .002
6. Changed both G and D learning rate to .0002
7. Changed D optimizer back to Adam with .0002 lr
8. Increased G learning rate to .002
9. Increased Dropout to .5, batch size to 64
10. Changed G activation from ReLU to Leaky ReLU

Here is some of the code for the model

Hyperparameters

```
SAMPLE_SIZE = 800
BATCH_SIZE = 32
LEAKY_SLOPE = 0.2
DROPOUT = 0.5
CODINGS_SIZE = 128
SCALE = 16

WEIGHT_STD = 0.02
WEIGHT_MEAN = 0
LEARNING_RATE_G = 0.001
LEARNING_RATE_D = 0.0002

tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
```

Weight initializer

```
weight_init = tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(stddev=WEIGHT_STD, mean=WEIGHT_MEAN, seed=42)
```

Layers and model

```
def conv_transpose(model, out_channels, k_size, s_size, batch_normalize=True):
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(out_channels, kernel_size=(k_size, k_size), 
                                         strides=(s_size, s_size), padding='same', use_bias=False,
                                         kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  if batch_normalize is True:
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  model.add(keras.layers.ReLU())
  #model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LEAKY_SLOPE))

  return model

def conv(model, out_channels, k_size, s_size, batch_normalize=True):
  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(out_channels, kernel_size=(k_size, k_size), 
                                strides=(s_size, s_size), padding='same',
                                kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  if batch_normalize is True:
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

  model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LEAKY_SLOPE))

  return model

def generator():
  model = keras.models.Sequential()

  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(scaled_size * scaled_size * 128, input_shape=(CODINGS_SIZE,), kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  model.add(keras.layers.Reshape([scaled_size, scaled_size, 128]))
  
  model = conv_transpose(model, 512, k_size=5, s_size=1)
  model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT))

  model = conv_transpose(model, 256, k_size=5, s_size=2)
  model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT))

  model = conv_transpose(model, 128, k_size=5, s_size=2)
  model = conv_transpose(model, 64, k_size=5, s_size=2)
  model = conv_transpose(model, 32, k_size=5, s_size=2)

  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), 
                                         padding='same', activation='tanh', 
                                         use_bias=True, kernel_initializer=weight_init))
  # model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='tanh', kernel_initializer=weight_init))

  return model

def discriminator():
  model = keras.models.Sequential()

  model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), 
                              padding='same', activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(LEAKY_SLOPE), 
                              input_shape=[64, 64, 3], kernel_initializer=weight_init)) 

  #model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT))
  model = conv(model, 64, k_size=5, s_size=2)

  #model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT))
  model = conv(model, 128, k_size=5, s_size=2)

  model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT))
  model = conv(model, 256, k_size=5, s_size=2)

  model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT))
  model = conv(model, 512, k_size=5, s_size=2)

  model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  return model

generator = generator()
discriminator = discriminator()
```

Optimizers

```
gen_optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE_G)
disc_optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE_D)
#disc_optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE_D)
```

Loss functions

```
def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output, apply_smoothing=True, apply_noise=True):
  real_output_mod = real_output
  fake_output_mod = fake_output

  if apply_noise:
    real_output_mod = noisy_labels(tf.ones_like(real_output_mod), 0.1)
    fake_output_mod = noisy_labels(tf.zeros_like(fake_output_mod), 0.1)
  
  if apply_smoothing:
    real_output_mod = smooth_labels(real_output_mod, 'positive')
    fake_output_mod = smooth_labels(fake_output_mod, 'negative')

  real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output_mod), real_output) #labels, outputs
  fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output_mod), fake_output)

  return real_loss + fake_loss

def generator_loss(fake_output, apply_smoothing=True):
  fake_output_mod = fake_output

  if apply_smoothing:
    fake_output_mod = smooth_labels(fake_output_mod, 'negative')

  return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output_mod), fake_output)
```

Training Loop

```
def train_step(images):
  noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[BATCH_SIZE, CODINGS_SIZE])

  with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
    generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)

    real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
    fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

    gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output, apply_smoothing=True)
    disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output, apply_smoothing=True, apply_noise=True)

  gen_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
  disc_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

  gen_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gen_gradients, generator.trainable_variables))
  disc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(disc_gradients, discriminator.trainable_variables))

  return gen_loss, disc_loss

plot_step = 1

def train_gan(dataset, epochs=50):
    all_gl = np.array([])
    all_dl = np.array([])
    G_mean = np.array([])
    D_mean = np.array([])

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch + 1, epochs))     

        G_loss = []
        D_loss = []

        for batch in dataset:
            g_loss, d_loss = train_step(batch)
            G_loss.append(g_loss)
            D_loss.append(d_loss)

        all_gl = np.append(all_gl, np.array([G_loss]))
        all_dl = np.append(all_dl, np.array([D_loss]))

        #Generate test images
        noise = tf.random.normal(shape=[BATCH_SIZE, CODINGS_SIZE])
        generated_images = generator(noise, training=False)

        #Print and Plot
        print("Generator Loss Mean:", np.mean(G_loss), "Std:", np.std(G_loss))
        print("Discriminator Loss Mean:", np.mean(D_loss), "Std:", np.std(D_loss))

        G_mean = np.append(G_mean, np.mean(G_loss))
        D_mean = np.append(D_mean, np.mean(D_loss))

        if ((epoch + 1) % plot_step == 0):
          plot_losses(G_loss, D_loss, all_gl, all_dl, G_mean, D_mean, epoch)
          plot_multiple_images(generated_images, 8)                
          plt.show()
```

(Yikes this post got long. Almost done)

Leaky ReLU in Generator, batch size 64 (all other hyperparameters are as shown)

Epoch 1: [image]

Epoch 5: [image]

Epoch 8: [image]

ReLU, batch size 32 (all other hyperparameters are as shown)

Epoch 3: [image]

After all that, my two questions:

1. How do I interpret and understand the data that I am seeing to then formulate a Google search to find an answer?
2. My generator is producing images with very similar color palettes. That doesn't seem right to me. Is that bad behavior or expected of a GAN in its early stages?

Comment: What is your `weight_init`?

Comment: Just added weight_init to the post. I don't know the specifics but it's supposed to help with normalization